# Trello due date for single elements on a checklist

Tags: trello

Isn't it possible to add a due date for single elements of a checklist instead of a whole card?
It would be very useful since within a card elements have different deadlines and priorities.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not possible. One workaround for you would be to reorganize your tasks into lists instead of cards. Doing this would allow you to create a list for a particular project/task, and then use the cards and their single due-dates as the individual tasks.

This isn't the best solution, but if you would like to request due-dates for activities in a card, I suggest emailing feature-ideas@trello.com - they will have to build this in.